# Android: QuickBlox callback not work

Tags: android, callback, quickblox, quickblox-android

Please help me!

Device A login and config chatService

Device B login and config chatService

Device B startCall and send notification to device A

Device A receive notification and send to CallSerivce

```
String message = data.get("message");
if(message != null){
    CallService.start(this, G.userQB);
}
```

My problem:

After start CallService, call backs and onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession session) not work and not receive anything and not set in logcat

CallService.java

```
public class CallService extends Service implements QBRTCClientSessionCallbacks, QBRTCSessionConnectionCallbacks {
    private static final String TAG = CallService.class.getSimpleName();
    private QBChatService chatService;
    private QBRTCClient rtcClient;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private int currentCommand;
    private QBUser currentUser;

    public static void start(Context context, QBUser qbUser, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallService.class);

        intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_COMMAND_TO_SERVICE, Consts.COMMAND_LOGIN);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_QB_USER, qbUser);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT, pendingIntent);

        Log.i("errorCheck", "pendingIntent => " + pendingIntent);

        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public static void start(Context context, QBUser qbUser) {
        start(context, qbUser, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        /*QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), G.APP_ID, G.AUTH_KEY, G.AUTH_SECRET);
        QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(G.ACCOUNT_KEY);
        QBSettings.getInstance().setEnablePushNotification(true);
        QBSettings.getInstance().isEnablePushNotification();*/

        createChatService();

        Log.d(TAG, "Service onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service started");

        parseIntentExtras(intent);

        startSuitableActions();

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    private void parseIntentExtras(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            currentCommand = intent.getIntExtra(Consts.EXTRA_COMMAND_TO_SERVICE, Consts.COMMAND_NOT_FOUND);
            pendingIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Consts.EXTRA_PENDING_INTENT);
            currentUser = (QBUser) intent.getSerializableExtra(Consts.EXTRA_QB_USER);
        }
    }

    private void startSuitableActions() {
        Log.i("errorCheck",currentCommand+ " == " + Consts.COMMAND_LOGIN);
        Log.i("errorCheck",currentCommand+ " == "+Consts.COMMAND_LOGOUT);
        if (currentCommand == Consts.COMMAND_LOGIN) {
            Log.i("errorCheck","?!: TO");
            startLoginToChat();
        } else if (currentCommand == Consts.COMMAND_LOGOUT) {
            Log.i("errorCheck","?!: OUT");
            logout();
        }
    }

    private void createChatService() {
        if (chatService == null) {
            QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true);
            chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
        }
    }

    private void startLoginToChat() {
        Log.i("errorCheck","?!: "+chatService);
        if (!chatService.isLoggedIn()) {
            Log.i("errorCheck","??????!!!!: "+chatService);
            loginToChat(currentUser);
        } else {
            Log.i("errorCheck", "NOLOGIN: "+chatService);
            sendResultToActivity(true, null);
        }
    }

    private void loginToChat(QBUser qbUser) {
        Log.i("errorCheck", "QQ: " + chatService);
        chatService.login(qbUser, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
                Log.d(TAG, "login onSuccess");
                startActionsOnSuccessLogin();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "login onError " + e.getMessage());
                sendResultToActivity(false, e.getMessage() != null
                        ? e.getMessage()
                        : "Login error");
            }
        });
    }

    private void startActionsOnSuccessLogin() {
        initPingListener();
        initQBRTCClient();
        sendResultToActivity(true, null);
    }

    private void initPingListener() {
        ChatPingAlarmManager.onCreate(this);
        ChatPingAlarmManager.getInstanceFor().addPingListener(new PingFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void pingFailed() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Ping chat server failed");
            }
        });
    }

    private void initQBRTCClient() {
        rtcClient = QBRTCClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        // Add signalling manager
        chatService.getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager().addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
                if (!createdLocally) {
                    rtcClient.addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                }
            }
        });

        // Configure
        QBRTCConfig.setDebugEnabled(true);
        SettingsUtil.configRTCTimers(CallService.this);

        // Add service as callback to RTCClient
        rtcClient.addSessionCallbacksListener(WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this));
        rtcClient.prepareToProcessCalls();
    }

    private void sendResultToActivity(boolean isSuccess, String errorMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity(): "+isSuccess+" , "+errorMessage+" , "+pendingIntent);
        if (pendingIntent != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sendResultToActivity()");
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_LOGIN_RESULT, isSuccess);
                intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_LOGIN_ERROR_MESSAGE, errorMessage);

                /*Intent newInt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                newInt.setData(Uri.parse("sms:0523737233"));
                newInt.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, newInt, 0);*/

                pendingIntent.send(CallService.this, Consts.EXTRA_LOGIN_RESULT_CODE, intent);
            } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                String errorMessageSendingResult = e.getMessage();
                Log.d(TAG, errorMessageSendingResult != null
                        ? errorMessageSendingResult
                        : "Error sending result to activity");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void logout(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.EXTRA_COMMAND_TO_SERVICE, Consts.COMMAND_LOGOUT);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    private void logout() {
        destroyRtcClientAndChat();
    }

    private void destroyRtcClientAndChat() {
        if (rtcClient != null) {
            rtcClient.destroy();
        }
        ChatPingAlarmManager.onDestroy();
        if (chatService != null) {
            chatService.logout(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                    chatService.destroy();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "logout onError " + e.getMessage());
                    chatService.destroy();
                }
            });
        }
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onBind)");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onTaskRemoved()");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        destroyRtcClientAndChat();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserNoActions(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStartClose(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartConnectToUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnectedTimeoutFromUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailedWithUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, QBRTCException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserNotAnswer(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallRejectByUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallAcceptByUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveHangUpFromUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionClosed(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectedToUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnectedFromUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionClosedForUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it in background ? of in both devices app was in forground ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start your service not when message is recived. In OnCreate of MainActivity:

startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CallService.class));

Your service have to implement interfaces:

public class CallService extends Service implements QBRTCClientSessionCallbacks,
        QBRTCSessionStateCallback<'QBRTCSession> {
...}